# Dependency error using Solr with Play in IntelliJ

Tags: solr, playframework, intellij-idea

I get this error message when running Play 2.1.2 and Solr 4.4.0 in IntelliJ. I didn't have this before and don't understand where it comes from. Tried cleaning project many times. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
[info] Resolving com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap#concurrentlinkedhashmap-

[warn]  module not found: org.restlet.jee#org.restlet;2.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   [...]\Play212\repository\local\org.restlet.jee\org.restlet\2.1.1\iv
ys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet/
2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet
/2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet/2.1.1/org.res
tlet-2.1.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.servlet;2.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   [...]\Play212\repository\local\org.restlet.jee\org.restlet.ext.serv
let\2.1.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.
ext.servlet/2.1.1/org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet
.ext.servlet/2.1.1/org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.servlet/2
.1.1/org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.1.1.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.restlet.jee#org.restlet;2.1.1: not found
[warn]  :: org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.servlet;2.1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.restlet.jee#
org.restlet;2.1.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.servlet;2.1.1: no
t found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to import the [Restlet framework](http://restlet.org/) as an external dependency.
This won't work, because by default, sbt (the build tool that Play uses) only checks Typesafe's repository and Maven central. I could not find Restlet at Maven central, and indeed, [on their download page, they write](http://restlet.org/download/maven):

> The Maven repository for Restlet is accessible from
>   http://maven.restlet.org and contains all Restlet JARs and third party
>   dependencies that aren't available in the main public Maven
>   repository. [...]

This means that you have to tell SBT somehow where to look for the dependency.
[A quick look into Play's documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTDependencies) reveals that you need to add a line to your `project/Build.scala`:

```
resolvers += "Restlet Repository" at "http://maven.restlet.org"
```